# How to make quicksilver remember custom trigger

Tags: macos, quicksilver

I am trying to make a custom trigger for my shell/apple script file to run so I can just launch my dev environment at the push of a button. So basically:

1. I have a shell script(and some apple script included) in ~ named start_server.sh which does 3 things:

   - start up solr server
   - start up memcached
   - start up script/server
2. I have a saved quicksilver command(.qs) that opens up start_server.sh(so start_server.sh, then the action is "Run in Terminal")
3. I created a custom trigger that calls this saved qs command.

I did that then tested it and it works. I then tried to double check it so I quit quicksilver and when I checked the triggers it just said: "Open (null)" as the action. I set the trigger again and when i restarted QS the same thing happened again. I don't know why but my old custom trigger to open terminal has worked since forever so why doesn't this one work?

Here's a screenie of the triggers after I restart QS: http://grab.by/4XWW

If you have any other suggestion on how to make a "push button" start for my server then please do so :) Thanks!

As an added note, I have already tried the steps on this thread but to no avail: http://groups.google.com/group/blacktree-quicksilver/browse_thread/thread/7b65ecf6625f8989

Here's a snippet of the supposed custom trigger in the Triggers.plist file:

```
<dict>
  <key>ID</key>
  <string>2903BB6B-94CB-4DE8-B00D-23973FA54F3D</string>
  <key>command</key>
    <dict>
  <key>actionID</key>
  <string>FileOpenAction</string>
  <key>directID</key>
  <string>/Users/eumir/Documents/QScripts/start-dx-command.qscommand</string>
</dict>
  <key>enabled</key>
  <true/>
  <key>keyCode</key>
  <integer>39</integer>
  <key>modifiers</key>
  <integer>1573160</integer>
  <key>onPress</key>
  <true/>
  <key>type</key>
  <string>QSHotKeyTrigger</string>
</dict>
```

Took out spaces in the folder and filename and it still returns null upon restarting.

Comment: Since this question is more about Quicksilver rather than programming, you'll probably have better luck with this question on Super User…

Comment: ok i'll post it there :) thanks!

Comment: Interesting thought about the space... If you haven't already, could you try two things? 1: rename the directory and see if it helps, 2: use the Terminal way to escape spaces in the tag and see if that works (e.g. .../Quicksilver\ Scripts/...)

Comment: i took out all spaces from the folder and filenames and it still doesn't work. I renamed Quicksilver Scripts to QScripts and the qscommand is now dashified: start-server-command.qscommand but I still get the null on restart

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you have the latest beta? There was a change in the version numbers recently.
Secondly, I created a custom trigger and it worked without problems through a restart of Quicksilver. I tried to figure out where the app stores the trigger information and found this properties file: ~/Library/Apllication Support/Quicksilver/Triggers.plist.
Custom entries get an ID like "FE2976DF-DF14-4191-B56C-8A5E68F48A84".
So what you could try is to create your trigger, copy the respective lines from the plist file, close Quicksilver and if the lines are gone (which I actually doubt) copy them in again.
If that doesn't work, at least you now know where to look.

Edit: the entries in the plist file are key-value pairs. The (null) might indicate that the target value is missing (at least as far as I can tell without being able to reproduce the problem).

Comment: yup since im using snow leopard, i have the B57 build. I just checked their site and it seems that it's still the build they have for 10.6? I just checked the triggers plist, ill update my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same problem, and found *some* luck getting triggers to stick if everything they point to is in the Catalog.  In other words, if I want to bind Cmd-Shift-Ctrl-k to "Open KeePass X", then I need to make sure that KeePassX.app is in the catalog.

Hope this helps,

-Chris